# Increasing Jetty/Solr heapspace

Tags: memory, solr, cygwin, jetty, heap-size

I'm running Cygwin with Jetty and Solr431.

Here's the contents of my .bat file I use to start Solr:

```
@echo off
C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin

bash -c "cd /cygdrive/c/Databases/apache-solr-3.5.0/example/; java -Dsolr.solr.home="./example-DIH/solr/" -jar start.jar"
```

After all is running a while the console window displays the error:

> Java heap space out of memory

How can I see how much heap space is allocated right now and how can I increase it? I read that I need to add a parameter like `-Xmx500M` to the startup command, but I don't know where.

**UPDATE**

with jps command I found the correct PID.

Then I got these results. I thought the `P` column would show the permitted heapspace, but I don't see if my command parameters had any effect?

**without any startup parameters**

jstat -gcutil 4932 5000

```
  S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
100,00   0,00  74,91  65,67  99,23    300    0,348     4    0,146    0,494
100,00   0,00  74,91  65,67  99,23    300    0,348     4    0,146    0,494
```

**with parameters**

bash -c "cd /cygdrive/c/Databases/apache-solr-3.5.0/example/;java -Dsolr.solr.home="./example-DIH/solr/" -jar -Xmx200m -Xmx400m start.jar" 
jstat -gcutil 2548 5000

```
  S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
  0,00  89,57  67,80  62,74  99,45    307    0,337     4    0,147    0,484
  0,00  89,57  67,80  62,74  99,45    307    0,337     4    0,147    0,484
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the `-Xmx500m` just before `start.jar`.

Additional information -

```
Initial Heap size -Xms<size>
Maximum Heap size -Xmx<size>
```

To find out the Heap Size for the current running process you need `jstat -gc <pid>`. For details have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html).

Comment: Thanks. And is there a way to see what is currently allocated? Also I believe there is a way to set a min-heap space and max heapspace? Do you know how?

Comment: Added the info in the answer

Comment: Thanks again. And how can I start jstat? I don't see in in the \bin folder of my JRE folder. And how do I find the pid? I checked my taskmanager but there I don't see either Jetty, Cygwin or Solr process, just a java.exe

Comment: any idea how I can start jstat and find the relevant pid? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look http://www.thecoderscorner.com/team-blog/java-and-jvm/8-gc-monitoring-in-java-with-jstat#.UnueLfmsh8E

Comment: I did, and added the test results. Can't make much sense of it though. Could you advise please? Thank you again!